# Why values are different when sending to influxdb

Tags: influxdb, esp32, arduino-ide

**First Code**

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <WiFiMulti.h>
WiFiMulti wifiMulti;
#define DEVICE "ESP32"
#include <InfluxDbClient.h>
#include <InfluxDbCloud.h>

// WiFi AP SSID
#define WIFI_SSID "Steven8"
// WiFi password
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "Skylim@86"
#define INFLUXDB_URL "https://us-east-1-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com"
#define INFLUXDB_TOKEN "d9gGniB2IP1LF0S3JRjoPkE7mbuEEENZbKUH-daOxJdu1YauRYa27o9fAmeOBbnnU9plVXnCEpGyj36VWIkHAA=="
#define INFLUXDB_ORG "d037a8a6fb755fff"
#define INFLUXDB_BUCKET "presentation"
#define TZ_INFO "UTC+8"

const int moisture_sensor = 2;
int vibration_sensor = 12;
int vib_data = 0; 
int moisture_data;
int moisture_read;


InfluxDBClient client(INFLUXDB_URL, INFLUXDB_ORG, INFLUXDB_BUCKET, INFLUXDB_TOKEN, InfluxDbCloud2CACert);


Point sensor("Data collection");

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Setup wifi
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  wifiMulti.addAP(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);

  Serial.print("Connecting to wifi");
  while (wifiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
   
  // Add tags
  sensor.addTag("device", DEVICE);
  sensor.addTag("location", "home");
  
  // Accurate time is necessary for certificate validation and writing in batches
  // For the fastest time sync find NTP servers in your area: https://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/
  // Syncing progress and the time will be printed to Serial.
  timeSync(TZ_INFO, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nis.gov");

  // Check server connection
  if (client.validateConnection()) {
    Serial.print("Connected to InfluxDB: ");
    Serial.println(client.getServerUrl());
  } else {
    Serial.print("InfluxDB connection failed: ");
    Serial.println(client.getLastErrorMessage());
  }
}

void loop() {

  vib_data = analogRead(vibration_sensor);
  moisture_read = analogRead(moisture_sensor);
  moisture_data = ( 100 - ( (moisture_read/4095.00) * 100 ) );
  // Get latest sensor readings

  sensor.clearFields();

  // Add readings as fields to point
  sensor.addField("Moisture", moisture_data);
  sensor.addField("Vibration", vib_data);

  if (wifiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) 
    Serial.println("Wifi connection lost");
  
  if (!client.writePoint(sensor))
  {
    Serial.print("InfluxDB write failed: ");
    Serial.println(client.getLastErrorMessage());
  }

  Serial.print("Vibration: ");
  Serial.println(vib_data);
  Serial.print("Mositure Percentage: ");
  Serial.println(moisture_data);
  delay(1000);
}
```

**Second Code**

```
const int moisture_sensor = 2;
int vibration_sensor = 12;
int vib_data = 0; 
int moisture_data;
int moisture_read;


void setup(void){
  Serial.begin(115200);     /* Set the baudrate to 115200*/
}


void loop() {

  vib_data = analogRead(vibration_sensor);
  moisture_read = analogRead(moisture_sensor);
  moisture_data = ( 100 - ( (moisture_read/4095.00) * 100 ) );
  // Get latest sensor readings


  Serial.print("Vibration: ");
  Serial.println(vib_data);
  Serial.print("Mositure Percentage: ");
  Serial.println(moisture_data);
  delay(1000);

}
```

So above shows two codes:
**the first** are just codes to compile to get the values from the two sensor connected to a esp32.

**the second** are codes to connect to influxdb data base to send the data collected from the two sensors.

Now my question is, looking at the first code, the serial monitor clearly shows the correct value of data being collected, and is changing whenever it detects changes. However, in the second code, when combining with the codes to send it to influxdb, connection all is good, can even see the bucket being activated at influxdb, but the values are wrong, only showing 0 and 100 for the sensors, wont response to any changes as well.

So I'm wondering is the problem a data format problem, or any connection problem, would love to hear from anyone, appreciate much thanks

So far I have tried changing the baud rate (thought that was the problem) but nothing changed, even changed the value to a float value but still the same. Currently stucked right now

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code, it's hard to read/work with. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: my bad, first time posting codes here, just changed its format